# What´s the running-time of checking all orders?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, list, big-o

This algorithm should check for each order in the orderList, if there´s a free car of the ordered type in the carList.

An order contains a type of an car you wish to order as well as pickup and return time. Now I´m stuck to find out if this can run in `O(nlog(n) + k)` where k indicates the number of different car-types.

```
public static boolean CheckAllOrder(List orderList, List carList) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < orderList.size(); i++) {
        int type = orderList.get(i).type;
        long start = orderList.get(i).start;
        long end = orderList.get(i).end;
        for (int j = 0; j < carList.size(); j++) {
            Car currentCar = carList.get(j);
            if (currentCar.type == type) {
                if (currentCar.occTil == 0 && currentCar.occSince == 0) {
                    currentCar.occSince = start;
                    currentCar.occTil = end;
                    count++;
                    break;
                } else if (currentCar.occTil < start) {
                    currentCar.occTil = end;
                    count++;
                    break;
                } else if (currentCar.occSince > end) {
                    currentCar.occSince = start;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == orderList.size()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I did test my code and it seems to work just fine.
I thought about using a hash-function over the car-types, so I only have to run through one smaller list (each list in my hash-table contains only cars of the same type). At least this is my idea.

Here´s the problem statement:

I do have k different car-types and n orders
I need to check if all orders can be processed, meaning there´s no order unable to be performed. This can only be due to not having a car of the specified type free yet. An order contains as already said the desired car-type, pickup and return-time.

How would you solve this?

Comment: I assume that for each car-type exactly one car is available? Then the problem can be reformulated as: at any moment in time for each car-type there is at most one order for that car-type.

Comment: The order nlog(n) suggest that you sort something using quicksort or mergesort. What if you sorted the orders on start time?

Comment: There are x cars of each car-type

Comment: I still need to run the whole order list even when sorted. Even when the orderList is sorted I need to run through the whole carList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. Bucket sort the orders by car type. O(n)
2. For the orders of each car type, [find the maximum number of overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245026/646887). O(n log(n) + k)
3. If the number found is greater than the number of cars for any type, return `false` (orders cannot be met). O(k)
4. return `true` (orders can be met). O(1)

Total complexity O(n log (n) + k)

Comment: That sounds great!

Comment: `check for each order`

Comment: Where do you get the O(n log(n) + k) for me it seems like O(n log(n))

Comment: There is a loop over the car types. This loop incurs a slight overhead that is proportional to the number of car types (`k`).