# How to get the number of collisions in overlapping sets?

Tags: algorithm

For a project which I am doing, I have a list of sets in the form of

`[ [start, end] ]`

For example

`[{1, 3} {2, 4} {5, 9} {6, 8} {7, 8}]`

The array is in sorted form.

I want to find the number of overlapping collisions. For example from the example dataset.

[image]

The result I want is like the following.

```
 Interval | Collisions
----------------------
 {7,8}    | 3
 {2,3}    | 2
 {6,7}    | 2
 {1,2}    | 1
 {3,4}    | 1
 {5,6}    | 1
 {8,9}    | 1
```

What is the ideal way to achieve it ?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but perhaps close enough: [Finding (number of) overlaps in a list of time ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244964/finding-number-of-overlaps-in-a-list-of-time-ranges).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate each list-element into *two* elements, one representing just the start and one representing just the end. Then, sort the result, giving you this:

- start at 1
- start at 2
- end at 3
- end at 4
- start at 5
- start at 6
- start at 7
- end at 8
- end at 8
- end at 9

Now you can iterate through the list, keeping track of how many sets you've entered and exited at each point.